# como puedo cambiar el formato de columna numerica a texto

Tags: r

como puedo visualizar un número largo completamente en rstudio?

por ejemplo tengo una columna con registros de tarjeta de credito y se ven de esta manera 788488181+15 y quiero ver completo el número

Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido @Dan Vilches a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se revisa la documentación de R `?is.integer`se indica que:

> Las implementaciones actuales de R utilizan enteros de 32 bits para vectores enteros, por lo que el rango de enteros representables se restringe a aproximadamente +/- 2 * 10 ^ 9

Es decir `7865156335004661 > 2*10^9 # se imprime TRUE`

En el caso que expones

```
df <- data.frame(
                 cliente=c("C1","C2","C3"), 
                 numTC=c(7865156335004661,7865533505604661,7865633505604661)
                 )
> df
  cliente        numTC
1      C1 7.865156e+15
2      C2 7.865534e+15
3      C3 7.865634e+15
```

Puedes convertir en texto la columna

```
df$numTC <- as.character(df$numTC)
df
  cliente            numTC
1      C1 7865156335004661
2      C2 7865533505604661
3      C3 7865633505604661
```

O también aplicar

```
print(df, digits = 15) # de acuerdo a lo proporcionado 788488181+15
  cliente            numTC
1      C1 7865156335004661
2      C2 7865533505604661
3      C3 7865633505604661
```